# Vue 3 Typescript Build 'this is undefined'

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vite

I am fairly new to Vue and am using Vite and TypeScript to make my project. Whenever I go to build I get a page of errors, mostly consisting of `Object is possibly 'undefined'` in parts of my template such as this:

```html
<input :value="this.$store.state.shareUrl"/>
```

Ignoring the typecheck and viewing the built page produces a blank page with the error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '$store')` in it, however the page works completely fine with the development version. Any ideas on how to fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Vue template, the `this` is implicit (that's why console.log doesn't work from the template), so you can skip that

```html
<input :value="$store.state.shareUrl"/>
```